# How to avoid download file rename?

Tags: html, file, ubuntu, download, rename

I have a file named `<h1>test.zip` on my webspace. When i try to download it, it get renamed as

```
 __h1_test.zip
```

Is there a way to leave the original filename to the downloaded file?

I'd like the downloaded file to keep the name `<h1>test.zip` once downloaded.

I'm using ubuntu at the moment and i can rename files as `<h1>test.zip` on my device.

Comment: The rename/overwrite/don't rename rules are governed by the application that is doing the downloading. I added the ubuntu tag for you but you will want to edit this with more details on how you are getting the file. The app you are using might be configurable or you might need a different method of downloading to achieve what you want.

Comment: What are you using to download the file? If the software is also compatible with Windows, it might use Windows rules when downloading, and therefore renaming it, since those characters are reserved in the Windows filesystem.

Comment: @Rodger,

The download is made by my browser, i have this zip file inside my webspace and the name is displayed correctly. When directly accessed at `https://mywebspace.com/<h1>test.zip` the file download is started but get saved as `_h1_.zip`

Comment: @Celsiuss,
I'm using google chrome browser. Should i try with a different software?

Comment: Looks like Chrome treats illegal characters in downloads the same on all OSes. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/master/base/i18n/file_util_icu.cc#68

Comment: Allowing this in chrome was originally opened in 2010 as a request, it was merged into a newer issue here but neither have any meaningful updates beyond people expressing frustration that it hasn't moved. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157225

Answer (score 0):

"<" this tag is coverted into "_"

so i suggest you , don't use "< >" tag ,  add another name.

No. The browser does that to prevent the user from accidentally overwriting an existing file with the same name and you have no control over this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to change it. None of them are perfect.

Go to chrome settings in your browser bar chrome://settings/, scroll down to advanced, click it, scroll down to downloads and check the box to prompt. You can then specify the same name so it isn't auto-renamed but it will prompt every time, even if there isn't a duplicate. You get used to it fast, so it isn't as big of a deal as it sounds like.

If that isn't what you want check out a Chrome extension that attempts to address this issue (not sure if it works with ubuntu though). There are numerous forums out there where people are asking for the same functionality and have been for years so don't expect Chrome to change default behavior... Here's one (untested by me) -> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloads-overwrite-alrea/lddjgfpjnifpeondafidennlcfagekbp?hl=en-US

Finally, depending on what you are doing (always downloading the same set of files for example) you could configure an FTP client or something else to pull the files and set the name instead of using a browser to pull them... you would be able to configure that more easily to overwrite. If you are downloading random things and just want to save bandwidth/etc when accidentally downloading the same file, then you likely need an extension/different browser/etc. to resolve it.